# Error when I use my val in function, but not when I access val on its own in REPL.

Tags: scala

I am writing Scala code to search a QuadTree. I'm fairly new to Scala, so this may be a simple question: Why do I get a `error: value rec not a member of QuadTree` when I try to use `tree.rec` in a function, BUT if I ask the REPL to evaluate `tree.rec`, it successfully returns the data?

Anyway, I've got these classes to start with:

```
case class Rectangle (minx: Int, maxx: Int, miny: Int, maxy: Int)

abstract class QuadTree
case class Node (value : Int, nw : QuadTree, ne: QuadTree, sw: QuadTree, se: QuadTree, rec: Rectangle) extends QuadTree
case class Leaf (value : Int, rec: Rectangle) extends QuadTree
case class Empty (value: Int, rec: Rectangle) extends QuadTree
```

So I'm defining a Rectangle, and then a QuadTree, which can has a value, and either contains a Node, a Leaf, or Empty.

Next I have a function that checks to see if two rectangles overlap called `rectangles_Overlap`, which returns `True` if two input Rectangles overlap, and returns `False` if there is no overlap.

If I define

```
val query = Rectangle(1, 8, 8, 16)
val tree1 = Node(13,Node(12,Leaf(7,Rectangle(1,4,12,16)),Leaf(3,Rectangle(4,8,12,16)),Leaf(2,Rectangle(1,4,8,12)),Empty(0,Rectangle(4,8,8,12)),Rectangle(1,8,8,16)),Empty(0,Rectangle(8,16,8,16)),Empty(0,Rectangle(1,8,1,8)),Leaf(1,Rectangle(8,16,1,8)),Rectangle(1,16,1,16))
```

If I want to get the size of the tree, I can type into the REPL

```
scala> tree1.rec
res0: Rectangle = Rectangle(1,16,1,16)
```

I can also use my `rectangles_Overlap` method to see if the query Rectangle overlaps with the tree Rectangle.

```
scala> rectangles_Overlap(query, tree1.rec)
res1: Boolean = true
```

But if I try to use `rectangles_Overlap(query, tree1.rec)` in another function, its unhappy!

```
def queryBoolean(query: Rectangle, tree: QuadTree): Boolean = {
    if(rectangles_Overlap(query, tree.rec)) {
        println("Yay they overlap so I can do other stuff...")
        // I want to add other code here after I get this working
        true
    } else { 
        println("Nah, they don't overlap, don't need to do anything")
        false
    }
}
```

And then call the function with `queryBoolean(query, tree1)`, I get this error:

```
<console>:17: error: value rec is not a member of QuadTree
       if (rectangles_Overlap(query, tree.rec)) {
```

So my question again is: Why can I evaluate `tree1.rec` in the REPL, but cannot use `tree.rec` in a function without an error?

My original thought was that perhaps I was overloading something... but `rec` is always a `Rectangle` in all of the `case clase ... extends QuadTree`. So I don't believe I am overloading anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is true. rec i.e. type of Rectangle, is **not** a member of QuadTree. If you change from QuadTree to Node, it will work. Otherwise it must be there in QuadTree too.

```
def queryBoolean(query: Rectangle, tree: Node): Boolean
```

Add to QuadTree as val (val is needed to access it), and then you need to override and call super constructor as below:

```
  abstract class QuadTree(val rec: Rectangle)
  case class Node (value : Int, nw : QuadTree, ne: QuadTree, sw: QuadTree, se: QuadTree, override val rec: Rectangle) extends QuadTree(rec)
  case class Leaf (value : Int, override val rec: Rectangle) extends QuadTree(rec)
  case class Empty (value: Int, override val rec: Rectangle) extends QuadTree(rec)
```

Comment: I need for it to be type `QuadTree`, so that it can handle `Node`s, `Leaf`s, and `Empty`s, so that will not work. When you say, "Otherwise it must bee there in the QuadTree too", what exactly do you mean? I tried changing it to `case class Rectanlges (*/some params/*) extends QuadTree` but this does not prevent the error.

Comment: This solution works, but I'm not exactly sure what's going on. Would you mind explaining what you're doing, a bit? I'm worried that the `override val` will create problems later down the road, especially as I try to match Node, Leaf, Empty. Is the `override val` an example of overloading? I will also check the docs. Thank you!

Comment: but it is simply.. how can you access a method or variable if it is not there in the class? So I put the val in the class i.e. the superclass where you need it. Then from subclasses I call superclass constructor. You gotta have the var/val/def in superclass since you are calling QuadTree.rec. The 'rec' needs to be in QuadTree.. that is where you are calling it.

Answer (score 1):

This is because `rec` is not defined for class `QuadTree`, but only for its subclasses, therefore there is no value to call. The reason that this works properly on REPL is because of the way it is defined. You define it as

```
val tree1 = Node(/*some params*/)
```

Which means it has type `Node`, instead of `QuadTree`. As `Node` has a defined `rec` parameter, everything works out fine. However in the method, you pass in a raw `QuadTree`, so no rec is defined.

To get it to work, either add `rec` to the `QuadTree` class, or pass in a specific subtype, which has the correct parameters defined.

Comment: Since `Node` extends `QuadTree`, wouldn't `tree1` be both a Node and QuadTree? Perhaps I am misunderstanding what you mean by "add rec to the QuadTree", but I changed the Rectangle class to `case class Rectangle (*/some params/*) extends QuadTree` and this still gives me the same error "value rec is not a member of QuadTree".  Sorry to be such a newbie, but can you explain more what you mean by "add rec to the QuadTree class". I'm also not sure what "pass in a specific subtype" means. Thanks for your help!